# Android Native SIP DTMF

Tags: android, sip

I am using `android SIP(android.net.sip)` for `VOIP` calling. Trying to send DTMF. In `SipAudioCall` Class of android two method has been given

```
void sendDtmf(int code, Message result)
Sends a DTMF code.

void sendDtmf(int code)
Sends a DTMF code.
```

I am thinking to use `sendDtmf(int code)` method to send DMTF. but I dont know how can I varify whether It is actually sent or not. After implementing this, I am not getting any tone at reciever/sender side. Calling to this giving me no effect (As its background processing is not visible ). Can anyone please let me know how can I varify the same? Also please explain me usage of second method `sendDtmf(int code, Message result)`.

Answer (score 2):

There are three main methods for sending DTMF with sip:

1. in-band [RTP payloads](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4733)
2. generated [DTMF tones](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual-tone_multi-frequency_signaling)
3. sip info messages (outdated and most likely not used)

Most likely it's using the in-band RTP payload packets.  Altho most sip stacks I know have some sort of option to select the type of DTMF to send.

Sorry I don't know anything about the inbuilt Android SIP stack, so I can't answer questions directly about there implementation.

What I would do to check that the DTMF is sent correctly is use something like [WireShark](http://www.wireshark.org/) to capture the RTP audio stream.  You can then use the wiresharks [voip call graph analysis](http://wiki.wireshark.org/VoIP_calls) option which will display the DTMF events in the RTP!

[image: VOIP Call Graph Analysis output]

Answer (score 1):

The android.net.sip has support only for dtmf mode RFC 2883.
You can easily see these messages with a software like wireshark and/or from your server side logs (or other peer logs).
Just make sure that the other party has support for this kind of dtmf (RFC 2883 support).

Answer (score 0):

I use Counterpath X-Lite V4.9.8 to help develop an Android OS SIP app using the native SIP library.  The X-Lite Softphone/Preferences/Calls should be set to "Send via RFC 2833".

Once you have an active SIP call with bi-directional audio, and you use yourcall.sendDtmf(5), as an example, during that call, you can hear the DTMF tones via the X-Lite app, with the tones lasting about 1/2 second each.

Comment: Also this answer might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43515604/tonegenerator-crashes-in-android-6-0/45179525#45179525