# ToneGenerator crashes in android 6.0

Tags: android, media, tone-generator

In my application i am using ToneGenerator to play simple sound. When test my application by compiling the application with 6.0, my application randomy crashing due to ToneGenerator init method. Below is the exception.

```
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Init failed 
04-21 12:34:05.497  7166  7166 E MyApplication:     at android.media.ToneGenerator.native_setup(Native Method) 
04-21 12:34:05.497  7166  7166 E MyApplication:     at android.media.ToneGenerator.<init>(ToneGenerator.java:746)
```

I am using the tone generator in below way.

```
    public ToneGenerator toneGenerator;
    public void playSound() { 
       if (toneGenerator == null) {
          toneGenerator = new ToneGenerator(AudioManager.STREAM_NOTIFICATION, 100);
        }
       toneGenerator.startTone(ToneGenerator.TONE_CDMA_ANSWER, 200);
   }


   public void releaseToneGenerator() {
      if (toneGenerator != null) {
        toneGenerator.release();
      }
    }
```

Any one faced same issue?..Previously my application was running on  4.4 and in that we did not observe any crash. In in 6.0 application is crashing

Comment: Naresh, Can you try calling the release function of the toneGenerator object right after the startTone is called ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Solved the issue by using handler.

```
private static void playTone(Context context, int mediaFileRawId) {
            Log.d(TAG, "playTone");
            try {
                if (toneGenerator == null) {
                    toneGenerator = new ToneGenerator(AudioManager.STREAM_NOTIFICATION, 100);
                }
                toneGenerator.startTone(mediaFileRawId, 200);
                Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
                handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        if (toneGenerator != null) {
                            Log.d(TAG, "ToneGenerator released");
                            toneGenerator.release();
                            toneGenerator = null;
                        }
                    }

                }, 200);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Exception while playing sound:" + e);
            }
        }
```

Comment: This is indeed what solved same issue on my Android 8.1 el-cheapo Redmi 6A: 
`java.lang.RuntimeException: Init failed
 at android.media.ToneGenerator.native_setup(Native Method)
 at android.media.ToneGenerator.<init>(ToneGenerator.java:746)
 at com.susu.mylib.core.MyRecognitionListener.<init>(MyRecognitionListener.java:176)
 at com.susu.mylib.core.MyActivity.startVoiceRecognitionActivity(MyActivity.java:1903)
 at com.susu.mylib.core.MyActivity$10.run(MyActivity.java:2287)
 at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:794)
 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
`

Answer (score 0):

Following is a Tone Generator based solution that appears stable, using an ontouch listener in a DialogFragment.  Set your onTouchListeners for each button in the OnViewCreated method, then use the following ontouch listener method, that continuously plays the selected DTMF tone over the SIP call while touching a button, then stops playing when the button is no longer touched.  The AnswerDialogListener is the callback to the MainActivity.

Edit:  I broke the previously working DTMF tone RFC2833 proper output by trying to fix a compiler warning by using toneType = ToneGenerator.TONE_DTMF_0; instead of toneType = toneGenerator.TONE_DTMF_0;

```
private View.OnTouchListener myTouchListener = new View.OnTouchListener(){
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        String callidText = callid;
        AnswerDialogListener listener = (AnswerDialogListener) getActivity();
        int streamType = AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC;
        int volume = 50;
        if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            switch (v.getId()) {
                case R.id.answer_dialog_0_button:
                    toneGenerator = new ToneGenerator(streamType, volume);
                    toneGenerator.getAudioSessionId();
                    listener.onAnswerResponse(callidText, "Keypad0");
                    toneType = toneGenerator.TONE_DTMF_0;
                    toneGenerator.startTone(toneType);
                    return true;
                case R.id.answer_dialog_1_button:
                    toneGenerator = new ToneGenerator(streamType, volume);
                    toneGenerator.getAudioSessionId();
                    listener.onAnswerResponse(callidText, "Keypad1");
                    toneType = toneGenerator.TONE_DTMF_1;
                    toneGenerator.startTone(toneType);
                    return true;
                case R.id.answer_dialog_2_button:
                    toneGenerator = new ToneGenerator(streamType, volume);
                    toneGenerator.getAudioSessionId();
                    listener.onAnswerResponse(callidText, "Keypad2");
                    toneType = toneGenerator.TONE_DTMF_2;
                    toneGenerator.startTone(toneType);
                    return true;
                case R.id.answer_dialog_3_button:
                    toneGenerator = new ToneGenerator(streamType, volume);
                    toneGenerator.getAudioSessionId();
                    listener.onAnswerResponse(callidText, "Keypad3");
                    toneType = toneGenerator.TONE_DTMF_3;
                    toneGenerator.startTone(toneType);
                    return true;
                case R.id.answer_dialog_4_button:
                    toneGenerator = new ToneGenerator(streamType, volume);
                    toneGenerator.getAudioSessionId();
                    listener.onAnswerResponse(callidText, "Keypad4");
                    toneType = toneGenerator.TONE_DTMF_4;
                    toneGenerator.startTone(toneType);
                    return true;
                case R.id.answer_dialog_5_button:
                    toneGenerator = new ToneGenerator(streamType, volume);
                    toneGenerator.getAudioSessionId();
                    listener.onAnswerResponse(callidText, "Keypad5");
                    toneType = toneGenerator.TONE_DTMF_5;
                    toneGenerator.startTone(toneType);
                    return true;
                case R.id.answer_dialog_6_button:
                    toneGenerator = new ToneGenerator(streamType, volume);
                    toneGenerator.getAudioSessionId();
                    listener.onAnswerResponse(callidText, "Keypad6");
                    toneType = toneGenerator.TONE_DTMF_6;
                    toneGenerator.startTone(toneType);
                    return true;
                case R.id.answer_dialog_7_button:
                    toneGenerator = new ToneGenerator(streamType, volume);
                    toneGenerator.getAudioSessionId();
                    listener.onAnswerResponse(callidText, "Keypad7");
                    toneType = toneGenerator.TONE_DTMF_7;
                    toneGenerator.startTone(toneType);
                    return true;
                case R.id.answer_dialog_8_button:
                    toneGenerator = new ToneGenerator(streamType, volume);
                    toneGenerator.getAudioSessionId();
                    listener.onAnswerResponse(callidText, "Keypad8");
                    toneType = toneGenerator.TONE_DTMF_8;
                    toneGenerator.startTone(toneType);
                    return true;
                case R.id.answer_dialog_9_button:
                    toneGenerator = new ToneGenerator(streamType, volume);
                    toneGenerator.getAudioSessionId();
                    listener.onAnswerResponse(callidText, "Keypad9");
                    toneType = toneGenerator.TONE_DTMF_9;
                    toneGenerator.startTone(toneType);
                    return true;
                case R.id.answer_dialog_asterisk_button:
                    toneGenerator = new ToneGenerator(streamType, volume);
                    toneGenerator.getAudioSessionId();
                    listener.onAnswerResponse(callidText, "KeypadAsterisk");
                    toneType = toneGenerator.TONE_DTMF_S;
                    toneGenerator.startTone(toneType);
                    return true;
                case R.id.answer_dialog_hash_button:
                    toneGenerator = new ToneGenerator(streamType, volume);
                    toneGenerator.getAudioSessionId();
                    listener.onAnswerResponse(callidText, "KeypadHash");
                    toneType = toneGenerator.TONE_DTMF_P;
                    toneGenerator.startTone(toneType);
                    return true;
            }
        }
        if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
            switch (v.getId()) {
                case R.id.answer_dialog_0_button:
                    toneGenerator.stopTone();
                    toneGenerator.release();
                    return true;
                case R.id.answer_dialog_1_button:
                    toneGenerator.stopTone();
                    toneGenerator.release();
                    return true;
                case R.id.answer_dialog_2_button:
                    toneGenerator.stopTone();
                    toneGenerator.release();
                    return true;
                case R.id.answer_dialog_3_button:
                    toneGenerator.stopTone();
                    toneGenerator.release();
                    return true;
                case R.id.answer_dialog_4_button:
                    toneGenerator.stopTone();
                    toneGenerator.release();
                    return true;
                case R.id.answer_dialog_5_button:
                    toneGenerator.stopTone();
                    toneGenerator.release();
                    return true;
                case R.id.answer_dialog_6_button:
                    toneGenerator.stopTone();
                    toneGenerator.release();
                    return true;
                case R.id.answer_dialog_7_button:
                    toneGenerator.stopTone();
                    toneGenerator.release();
                    return true;
                case R.id.answer_dialog_8_button:
                    toneGenerator.stopTone();
                    toneGenerator.release();
                    return true;
                case R.id.answer_dialog_9_button:
                    toneGenerator.stopTone();
                    toneGenerator.release();
                    return true;
                case R.id.answer_dialog_asterisk_button:
                    toneGenerator.stopTone();
                    toneGenerator.release();
                    return true;
                case R.id.answer_dialog_hash_button:
                    toneGenerator.stopTone();
                    toneGenerator.release();
                    return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
};
```

Following is a snippet of the if statement in the MainActivity callback handler to output the DTMF on the active SIP call:

```
if (response.equals("Keypad0")) {
            try {
                if (call != null) {
                    call.sendDtmf(0);
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else if (response.equals("Keypad1")) {
            try {
                if (call != null) {
                    call.sendDtmf(1);
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```